# Error with 'com.apple.developr.aps-environment' when validating mac application on xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

In an application I made for Mac, when I ran the process for validating the archive, it came up with the error:

```
The archived application has entitlements that require Mac App Store distribution. 
The invalid entitlements were: 

com.apple.developer.aps-environment.
```

I looked at this link: [Enabling Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html) and the entitlement, I think, is in relation to the push notifications.

I tried adding the
`com.apple.developer.aps-environment`

to my entitlements file as a `boolean set to YES`, but the error still came up.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error states that you're **already** requesting the entitlement, doesn't it..? Do you have a valid Apple Developer ID to sign the app?

Comment: Yes I have a valid apple developer ID, and have managed to sign and validate the application before.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're maybe trying to sign the app for distribution outside the App Store, and Xcode is telling you it's not going to let you do that because you're using App Store only features.

I'm no expert in signing stuff, but to get my last app to submit I signed it with the "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:..." identity, not my "Developer ID:" identity. The latter is only for when you're distributing apps directly to customers from your own website.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a boolean. It's a string that's either 'development' or 'production'. It's also only for apple store only.